# Passing Firebase data from TableViewCell to another ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, segue

Hi I'm trying to pass the data retrieved from Firebase and displayed in a tableViewCell to another viewController - a more detailed view controller. Hoping you can help?

The idea is that the Cell displays a city and country and when tapped it goes to a new view controller displaying further info for that city. So the further info is; city, country, location, photoUrl.

I have been at this for countless hours trying to figure out what to code in the didSelectRowAt and the prepare for segue.

Thanks in advance.

Database:

[image]

Here is the trip destination class:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase

class tripDestinations {

var country: String?
var city: String?
var location: String?
var photoUrl: String?

init(cityText: String?, countryText: String?, locationText: String?, photoUrlString: String?) {
    self.city = cityText
    self.country = countryText
    self.location = locationText
    self.photoUrl = photoUrlString
}

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    city = snapshotValue["city"] as? String
    country = snapshotValue["country"] as? String
    location = snapshotValue["location"] as? String
    photoUrl = snapshotValue["photoUrl"] as? String
}
```

And here is the first tableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class HomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var trips = [tripDestinations]()
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var refHandle: UInt!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        loadTrips()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return trips.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let cityLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        cityLabel.text = trips[indexPath.row].city

        let countryLabel = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        countryLabel.text = trips[indexPath.row].country

        return cell
    }

    func loadTrips() {
        refHandle = ref.child("destinations").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                print(dictionary)

                let city = dictionary["city"]
                let country = dictionary["country"]
                let location = dictionary["location"]
                let photoUrl = dictionary["photoUrl"]

                self.trips.insert(tripDestinations(cityText: city as? String, countryText: country as? String, locationText: location as? String, photoUrlString: photoUrl as? String), at: 0)

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let destinationController = segue.destination as! DetailTableViewController
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below lines of code in detail view controller

```
var destination : tripDestinations? {
            didSet {
                print(destination?.country!)
            }
        }
```

Add below line in didSelectRowAt method

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
```

Add below line Prepare for segue method and try

```
destinationController.destination = self.trips[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Thanks it worked it's now passing data and I can see it in the console but I can't figure out how to display it in the new table view controller. I tried the same way I did in the previous table view controller in the cell for row at func. I tried this way but no luck?

Comment: Use this code in CellForRowAtIndexPath and see if it prints the country in the console or not ?  guard let country = destination?.country,
        let city = destination?.city else {
            return
        }
        print(country)
        countryLabel.text = country

Comment: Perfect thank you, all working! Thanks for your help, saved me hours of trawling the internet for solutions!

Answer (score 0):

In your didselectRowat call performsegue function just like below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
    }
```

Create array in your DetailTableViewController

```
var tripsData = [tripDestinations]()
```

add these lines in your performsegue function

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destinationController = segue.destination as! DetailTableViewController

            destinationController.tripsData = trips[indexPath?.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome @JordanEverett